# static object c++ "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, static

I have the following code:

```
// header.h
class Outer
  {


       class Mid
        {
           Mid();
          ~Mid ();
        };

       class Inner
       {
           private:
               static Mid m_mid;
       };
   };
```

When I define the static private object in the cpp file, it gives me an error saying Mid does not name a type:

```
 // header.cpp:
  # include "header.h"
  Mid Mid::m_mid;
 {Begin definitions for Outer, Mid and Inner from here}
```

Any clue why the compiler would complain about this ? : Mid does not name a type

Comment: You forgot a semicolon at the end of your class declarations

Comment: Ohh yeah I have it in my code. This is just a sample skeleton I came up with quickly.

Comment: Any reason to downvote ?

Comment: @noobcoder You should always post the exact code that is giving you the problem; if you're writing a new reproducible example (which is a good practice) you should run it to make sure. Otherwise, how do you know it still gives the error? (If it matters, it wasn't my downvote either)

Comment: my apologies. Editing the question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but anyway, it helps to not insert arbitrary code errors in example code when posting a question. Otherwise people see only those and move on. You should edit and fix it.

Comment: `Mid Mid::m_mid;` m_mid is in class Inner, not class Mid...

Comment: @Borgleader I want to define the member m_mid inside of Inner due to the implementation. So it needs to be there. Any workarounds ?

Comment: I'm downvoting because this is frankly quite silly. There is no reason to expect this definition to compile successfully and this question is not going to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: @noobcoder That's my point, Mid::m_mid means m_mid is in Mid, but its not, look at your class declaration.

Comment: @Borgleader yeah, I got my mistake now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no class `Mid`; there is also no member of `Mid` named `m_mid`.

There is, however, a class `Outer::Mid`, and a class `Outer::Inner` that has a member named `m_mid`. Write those instead. :)

```
Outer::Mid Outer::Inner::m_mid;
```

Comment: Makes all sense now. :)

Comment: @noobcoder: Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You have to fully qualify the type name and the member name.

```
Outer::Mid Outer::Inner::m_mid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are nothing about static private object, there come up because of the following.

1. ; is missed at the end of each class definition
2. construct is private, but should be public
3. namespace is missed when declare m_mid;

after fixed, the following works

```
class Outer
{
public:
    class Mid
    {
    public:
       Mid(){}
       ~Mid (){}
    };

    class Inner
    {
    private:
        static Mid m_mid;
    };
};
int main(){
    Outer::Mid m_mid;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may compile, bit it does not define the static member; instead you have an unused local variable with the same name.

Comment: Yes you are right. Use "Outer::Mid Outer::Inner::m_mid;" to define the m_mid that declared as static Mid in Inner